# get attribute values from string key

Tags: entity-framework, attributes

Hi i need to obtain the value of attribute of a model by passing the name of attribute like string.

ex

model["ModelID"]

is there any method for this?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luca, I am going to take a small liberty and rephrase your question for you and then hopefully answer it. So I could be one right or twice wrong..

> Hi, I would like to get the value of a
>   an object's property using a string
>   key, similar to
>
> `var id=model["ModelId"];`.
>
> Is this possible?

to which would answer:

One way is to use the Reflection api.

```
model.GetType().GetProperty("ModelId").GetValue(model,null);
```